# Multiple "msgid" for an "msgstr" in gettext

Tags: gettext

Is it possible to make two or more *msgids* matching one *msgstr*?

For example, both ***('list.empty')*** and **('list.null')** return `"There is no any objects yet."`

**If I write this way in po file:**

```
msgid "list.empty"
msgid "list.null"
msgstr "There is no any objects yet."
```

**It just errors with "missing 'msgstr'":**

However,

```
msgid "list.empty"
msgstr "There is no any objects yet."

msgid "list.null"
msgstr "There is no any objects yet."
```

Looks and works fine but stupid, because once I change one msgstr without another, they return different result.

Does anyone have any better hacks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are approaching `gettext` in the wrong way, here is how it works:

- `msgid` is required for each entry
- `msgctxt` is optional and is used to differentiate between two `msgid` records with same content that may have different translations.
- `(msgid, msgctxt)` is the unique key for the dictionary, if `msgctxt` is missing you can consider it `null`.

You should read the [gettext documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files) before implementing as it's not always straightforward.

In your case, this is how you are supposed to implement it:

```
msgctxt "list.empty"
msgid "There is no any objects yet."

msgctxt "list.null"
msgid "There is no any objects yet."
```

Comment: It spells msgctxt not msgctx.