# Is it possible to write shorthand in cakephp 3 translation files?

Tags: translation, cakephp-3.0, po

My src\Locale\pr_IR file is like

```
msgid "Mobile"
msgstr "موبایل"

msgid "mobile"
msgstr "موبایل"

msgid "MoBiLe"
msgstr "موبایل"
```

Is it possible to convert this to something like

```
msgid "Mobile"
msgid "mobile"
msgid "MoBiLe"
msgstr "موبایل"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not, at least not without creating your own [**PO file parser**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.0-RC1/src/I18n/Parser/PoFileParser.php) that would handle such an invalid/non-standard PO format.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Creating Message Parsers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#creating-message-parsers)**
- **http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files**
- **[Multiple "msgid" for an "msgstr" in gettext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895205/multiple-msgid-for-an-msgstr-in-gettext)**